# How to access stores in a shared function in a Svelte app?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I have a Svelte app that will do its own routing using the browser history API. I want to provide a `changeRoute(newRouteDetails)` function and make it available to all the components in the Svelte app. It will need access to various Svelte stores' values to stash the current state before changing to the new URL.

At first, I thought I might be able to define the function in the stores.js file, export it and use it in my components.

I thought I could access the stores' current values using `$storeName` but this doesn't work (I think because the function lives in a .js file and not a .svelte file, but it's not a svelte component, so I didn't think it should be in a .svelte file).

The only ways I have found to get around this are: use `get()` but it's advised against in the [docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#get), or by requiring that the thing calling the function passes in all the store values.

But I feel I might be missing something?

I've made three REPLs (still no idea what that stands for!) which demonstrate the problem using a simple hello world style app, in which I want the `updateName` function to combine a passed-in value and a value from a store to update the name.

1. [Broken version](https://svelte.dev/repl/224b4e0c861f4aec91f76171805c2fbb)
2. [Using get()](https://svelte.dev/repl/57836d1dfa394f9cad534eb243517893)
3. [Passing values as args](https://svelte.dev/repl/d22037de12b543caadb886acca2ad5a6)

Assuming (2) is somehow "not the svelte way", and that (3) is fine if you only have one or two stores, but doesn't seem complete either (e.g. what if the function wanted to wait on a `tick()` and *then* obtain an updated store value?), how can we share a function like this?

Answer (score 1):

Using `get` *is* the correct way here, the docs say it is not recommended because usually it is not needed. What they advise against is doing things like this in a store where a direct subscription would be better:

```html
 let value = 0;
 function handleClick() {
   value = get(store);
 }
```

As the docs also mention

> Occasionally, you may need to retrieve the value of a store to which you're not subscribed. get allows you to do so.

The keyword here is **occasionally**, which I think is your case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main question *"is it ok to use get()?"* has already been answered well!
The docs say

> ...the value of a store to which you're not subscribed...

so I just wanted to add: if you want to avoid get(), your logic should be changed in the way, that it runs automatically triggered by a store change. So not 'click button -> run function which then collects values via get()' but instead 'click button -> change store value -> function execution is triggered reactively'
In the case with the router logic this might not be applicable and using get()  might be fine and the way to go.
Since the example you gave with the name and greeting was a bit different though, I thought I 'd just make two versions with a different approach using a derived and custom store, simply to illustrate other ways -> [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/97c26b388524451dab705153a42de552?version=3.44.1)